# Cannot place phone call using Mac OSX El Capitan

Tags: ios, facetime

I have iOS 10 installed on my phone.  As far as I can tell everything is configured properly.  A number of support documents out there for iOS 9 list verifying that "Use cellular data" is enabled on the phone in FaceTime settings, however this is not an option in iOS 10.

I did verify under Settings > Cellular that FaceTime was indeed enabled.

Everything I've read online is that since Yosemite, I should be able to place phone calls to any telephone number using features from that release such as is outlined here: https://9to5mac.com/2014/10/19/make-phone-calls-from-your-mac-and-ipad/comment-page-1/

Unfortunately, most numbers in my Contacts app have the dial button disabled.

Both devices are on the same Wifi network (phone and macbook).

**Update**:  I was able to resolve this by logging out of iCloud on my Mac in System Preferences and then logging back in.  My device did not show up on Settings > Phone > Calls on Other Devices until I did this.

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to FaceTime to a non-Apple device. They both must have the Facetime app. (Middle East countries doesn't have the FaceTime app.)

Think of it like a Viber call: both parties need the app before one can phone the other.

Comment: Per this article (https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18756?locale=en_US), I should be able to place calls with my Mac.  It doesn't note anything about requiring an iDevice on the other end.  Perhaps I phrased the question wrong?  I just want to place a call from my Mac.

Comment: Would like to downvote this, but not to 125 reputation limit yet to do so.  Calls placed on behalf of the Continuity feature are done so inside the Facetime app on a Mac, so the above statement is inaccurate.http://www.apple.com/macos/continuity/

Comment: You never mentioned cellular calls, you just said Facetime and tagged it `facetime`... (We can see your edits) ..but glad you fixed it. :)